# How to join two table without common attributes

Tags: sql-server

Guys please help me to find a solution....  I want join two table, there is a common variable but in one table that store  with ',' as varchar, that is id in other table. How can join with two table and take values

Comment: Is the common attribute is `id` and `table1` have id = `22,12` and `table2` have id = `2212`, in this way?

Comment: add example tables and data, please

Comment: Consider changing your table structure. You should not store comma separated values in a column

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

**1st table**

```
Name    | Course Id
====================
Zishan  | 1,2,3                                           
Ellen   | 2,3,4
```

**2nd table**

```
course id | course name 
=======================
   1      |  java
   2      |  C++
   3      |  oracle
   4      |  dot net
```

**Query**

```
SELECT names.name,
       courses.course_name
FROM   names
       INNER JOIN courses
               ON ',' + names.course_ids + ',' LIKE '%,'
                                                    + Cast(courses.course_id AS NVARCHAR(20))
                                                    + ',%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ID VARCHAR(MAX),VALUE VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (ID INT,VALUE VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('21,22','ABC'),('30,15','DEF')
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (2122,'GHI'),(3020,'JKL')

SELECT  T1.*,T2.*
FROM    @T1 T1
JOIN    @T2 T2 ON T2.ID = CAST(REPLACE(T1.ID,',','') AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be pretty simple...

If your table layout is what Mukesh has, the query can be made simpler:

```
SELECT n.name,
       c.course_name
FROM 
       names n
INNER JOIN 
       courses c ON '%' + c.courseid + '%' LIKE n.courseid
```